# .Net core AntiForgeryToken is not matching with server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, iis

I am working on Asp.Net core application and Application is running fine on my local but I am not able to validate Antiforgery token on the server.
Error: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted."

Below is the code.

```js
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnstart").click(function(e) {
            let productvals = $("#productlist").val();
            let runnumber = $("#runnum").val();
            let btnval = $("#btnstart").val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("
                CheckRunnumber ","
                Validation ")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    runnumber: $('#runnum').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success == "True") {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.btnstartval);
                        //$("#Runform").submit();
                        if ($("#Runform").valid()) {
                            console.log(productvals, runnumber, data.btnstartval);
                            console.log(gettoken());
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Url.Action("
                                RunCase ", "
                                CallService ")",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    products: productvals,
                                    runnumber: runnumber,
                                    button: data.btnstartval,
                                    __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken()
                                },
                                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert("Error");
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            function gettoken() {
                var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
                token = $(token).val();
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

To compare this token I logged it on the console window and it is different then the one under Application tab inside the inspect window.

Below is the error log I am getting.

```html
2020-10-08T13:00:05.5115395-05:00 0HM3BMFTTVJ22:00000001 [ERR] An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. (348bf365)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {dbeef040-4a73-45ff-8b62-064683015ea1} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
2020-10-08T13:00:35.9439222-05:00 0HM3BMFTTVJ22:00000004 [INF] Process not found (d326d86c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you host your application on shared server backend or else? It seems that your application doesn't have enough permission to read the key.

I suggest you could try to modify the IIS application pool identity to have enough permission to read the key. More details ,you could refer to below steps:

1.Open IIS management console:

2.Select your application pool

3.Modify the application pool identity to local system or other domain account which has enough permission to access your keys.

[image]

If this couldn't solve your issue, could you please share the startup.cs settings?